# How to create sqlite database in unit test and remove it after all test from class done C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, unit-testing, nunit

How to create SQLite database in unit test and remove it after all test from class done C# .net

I need to create db, add some file there and remove it after unit test class methods are done.

Comment: So a unit test should not be creating a db. A unit test should be only testing an isolated piece of code and should be mocking all db interactions. What you are describing is either a service test or a intergration test. However just follow something like this: https://dotnetcorecentral.com/blog/sqlite-for-unit-testing-in-net-core/

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is rather an integration test as you've mention. I've been on this website and here they mocking on DB context. In my project, I am using ado.net so it makes it harder. That's why I'd like to create a DB as it hard to mock

Comment: Is "mocking ADO.NET is hard" the only reason you are implementing integration tests instead of unit tests? If so, I think you'd be better off refactoring your code to support unit testing. Hide your ADO.NET data access behind an interface so you can inject a mock implementation at runtime. Creating a test database introduces its own set of challenges.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at this tutorial: https://dotnetcorecentral.com/blog/sqlite-for-unit-testing-in-net-core/

```
[Test]
public void Test_Get_By_Id()
{
    var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
    connection.Open();

    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EmployeeContext>().UseSqlite(connection).Options;

    using (var context = new EmployeeContext(options))
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    using (var context = new EmployeeContext(options))
    {
        context.Employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Address = "123 Street", HomePhone = "111-111-1111", CellPhone = "222-222-2222" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var context = new EmployeeContext(options))
    {
        var provider = new EmployeeProvider(context);
        var employee = provider.Get(1);

        Assert.AreEqual("John", employee.FirstName);
    }
}
```

You create an inmemory db then you make sure the database is created, you add anything you want to check and then you can do any querys/asserts to check its working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

just create this method and use the "db" for other facts (tests).
hope works for you..

```
    private ApplicationDbContext GetContext()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder().
            UseSqlite("Data Source = nameOfYourDatabase.db")
            .Options;

        var db = new ApplicationDbContext(options);

        db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        db.Database.EnsureCreated();

        return db;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CreateDatabaseTest()
    {
        using var db = GetContext();
    }
```